# Fuel UX Tree get unselected data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, fuelux

I Use Fuel UX tree plugin. And I need to get information about unselected item when mouse click.
At first, all items in tree are selected, and when I click on tree item, it's become unselected, but I cannot get information about this item, because this code:

```
$('#tree1').on('selected', function (evt, data) {
     console.log(data);
}
```

returned only selected items. Are the way to get information about unselected items in tree?

Comment: according to the documentation, "This event is fired when item/items has been selected. An object containing {info: data} is returned. data represents an array of selected items". So I doubt there is a way for you to do this with the selected event

Comment: And is there an opportunity to add html attribute/class to tree item?

Comment: I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional "unselected" event into my copy of the fuelUX code around line 100...

```
if($el.hasClass('tree-selected')) {
    this.$element.trigger('unselected', {info: $el.data()});
    $el.removeClass('tree-selected');
    $el.find('i').removeClass(this.options['selected-icon']).addClass(this.options['unselected-icon']);
} else {
...
```

This sends me the data associated with the unselected item as well. Hope it helps you.